# Varchar conversions undeclared table variables and other errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I really need help with this.  Can anyone see issues with the below code?  All the `SelectedValue` items are just SQL databound dropdown boxes and 2 textboxs, one with a calendar control and the other for simple string input.  A user goes to the page, fills it in.  I grab `DateTime.Now` for the `Job_Date` field, the rest are grabbing the values entered except for `Job_DueDate` which grabs the date (Entered via the calendar control as 7/06/2013 which is in DD/MM/YYYY format), converts it to `DateTime` and adds 17 hours so that by default the Due Date for a job is 5pm of the selected day.  After insertion, I then want to `OUTPUT` the newly created ID in `tbl_Job` into a field called `Job_ID` in the `tbl_job_contacts` table.  I execute this in a manner that I get that ID returned to me which I store in `result`.  In the second `INSERT` query, I insert that result and another `SelectValue` into the `tbl_job_contacts` table and then refresh the page.

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

    var dd = Convert.ToDateTime(DueDate.Text);
    DueDate.Text = dd.AddHours(17).ToString();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HSEProjRegConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_Job(Job_Date,Job_Origin_ID,Job_Department_ID,Job_Priority_ID,Job_Project_ID,Job_Status_ID,Job_DueDate,Job_Project_Item) OUTPUT tbl_Job.Job_ID INTO tbl_job_contacts(Job_ID) VALUES ('" + dt + "', '" + ReferenceOrigin.SelectedValue + "', '" + Department.SelectedValue + "', '" + Priority.SelectedValue + "', '" + Project.SelectedValue + "', '" + Status.SelectedValue + "', '" + DueDate.Text + "', '" + ProjectItem.Text + "')", conn);
    int result = ((int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_job_contacts(Job_ID,Contact_ID) VALUES ('" + result + "', '" + Sponsor.SelectedValue + "')", conn);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), false);
}
```

I keep getting errors no matter what I chop out or modify.  Either varchar conversion to DateTime is an out of range value which doesn't tell me which one because there are 2, or `Must Declare Local Variable` with the `OUTPUT` even though I think I am using what the MSDN site says.  Even a NullException error when I tried to modify it in a way to see if I could find out which DateTime was wrong.  I am really struggling with this and am hoping someone can help me sort out where my code is wrong.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: can you post database structure here? I think there is a problem with data structure and data type you are passing in.

Comment: Also used parameterised query otherwise sql injection will harm your data

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far.  I will work on the concatenation before I release this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're output clause should be:

```
 OUTPUT inserted.Job_ID
```

In the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), you should reference the `inserted` pseudo-table, not any actual table. And because you're wanting to capture the result back in your C# code, you don't want to use the `INTO` syntax - you want it to produce a result set instead.

As to the date conversion issues, I agree with @marc_s's comment - use [parameterised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) queries, and more importantly, **don't** convert date/datetime values to strings - keep them as `Date` values and let ADO.Net deal with translating them *directly* into SQL `datetime` values.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far.  The `OUTPUT` is now resolved so that is great.  One issue down.  I have sorted out some more issues as well I think but still some more to go.  I'll work on it over the weekend (Almost 5pm here!) and see how I go next week.